# Let$ f: (0, 1) → \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function at each point of $(0, 1)$ and such that $|f '(x)|<1$ for all $x\in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we define $A_n = f(1/n)$.  We have to show that $\lim_{n →\infty} A_n$ exists. I think that I have to prove that $f(1/n)$ is Cauchy using the Rolle's theorem. And if it is Cauchy it is convergent because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.  But I do not know if to prove this I have to apply some theorem or there is another way to see that $f(1/n)$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

For There is an $N > 0$ such that :$ \left|\dfrac{1}{m} - \dfrac{1}{n}\right| < \epsilon$ if $m,n > N$ since $\{\dfrac{1}{n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Thus using mean value theorem, and  if $m,n > N \implies |a_m - a_n|= \left|f(\frac{1}{m}) - f(\frac{1}{n})\right|= |f'(c)|\left|\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{m}\right|< 1\cdot \epsilon = \epsilon$, proving $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence , so it converges.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that by the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), for $m> n>0$ there is $t\in(1/m,1/n)$ such that
$$f(1/n)-f(1/m)=f'(t)(1/n-1/m)\implies |f(1/n)-f(1/m)|<|1/n-1/m|.$$
Now the sequence $(1/n)_n$ is convergent and therefore is Cauchy. Can you take it from here?